# how to detecting ioncube version

Tags: php, encode, ioncube

i want to know how i know what is version is encode with ioncube

i have file but i dont know what version use to encode it

any idea to fight out what is ver??

simple of file

```
<?php //004e5
if(!extension_loaded('ionCube Loader')){$__oc=strtolower(substr(php_uname(),0,3));$__ln='ioncube_loader_'.$__oc.'_'.substr(phpversion(),0,3).(($__oc=='win')?'.dll':'.so');if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}$__ln='/ioncube/'.$__ln;$__oid=$__id=realpath(ini_get('extension_dir'));$__here=dirname(__FILE__);if(strlen($__id)>1&&$__id[1]==':'){$__id=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__id,2));$__here=str_replace('\\','/',substr($__here,2));}$__rd=str_repeat('/..',substr_count($__id,'/')).$__here.'/';$__i=strlen($__rd);while($__i--){if($__rd[$__i]=='/'){$__lp=substr($__rd,0,$__i).$__ln;if(file_exists($__oid.$__lp)){$__ln=$__lp;break;}}}if(function_exists('dl')){@dl($__ln);}}else{die('The file '.__FILE__." is corrupted. Ensure that you use binary mode when transferring files with FTP and disable the 'TAR smart cr/lf feature' if using WinZIP\n");}if(function_exists('_il_exec')){return _il_exec();}echo('Site error: the file <b>'.__FILE__.'</b> requires the ionCube PHP Loader '.basename($__ln).' to be installed by the website operator. If you are the website operator please use the <a href="http://www.ioncube.com/lw/">ionCube Loader Wizard</a> to assist with installation.');exit(199);
?>
E؟¦g†s،™ovقb5؛‌éچgT'حے$L‏ٌ£–¯ اî¸i أ جb¹‚ڑx،^ٍwژ¶4b»£kxK~³*D‰•%Œٹôص²M]Z¦ْDف‎ج€کچ¬PX§ظ¼عœ£W ٍC}~خءJ&¯éùoغَ‘و½\·¶sBشش-تن¼–،ز8-+Hب|^_6?َŒ؛qح(’œeeپ-¥ڑ…jMًKه1w±A‡—Wâô,â[:\ƒIâ  ف3ژ^½«‡H'H غsِي±Uo•}پ}i(!‎ّ{q+Hح،ق²oBük‍“tTژ‍”ارےœہ$ڑ™mIذê‰سcس2y*
```

Comment: why you want to know the version?

Comment: http://forum.ioncube.com/viewtopic.php?p=1056&sid=e38186c21e2b0634e52b67ec58f9172b#1056

Comment: i just wanna know cuz i have localhost and need to install correct version of ioncube to load file

Comment: I think you just need to install the loader from http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php without knowing the version.